# Representation of a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble with proving the following implication:

Prove that if (-4) is a square $ \pmod{p} $, then $ p $ is representable as $ x^2 + 4y^2 $ in  $\mathbb{Z}$.

So I was thinking that maybe Fermat's theorem would be useful if I could prove that $ (-1) $ is a square in $ \mathbb{Z}_p $, but nothing's crossed my mind how to prove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p=2$ the statement is trivial, so let's assume that $p$ is odd.

Since $2$ has an inverse, say, $\alpha$, and $-4$ is a square, then $-1\equiv -4\alpha^2\pmod p$, so $-1$ is a square.

That is, there exists some $m$ such that $p|m^2+1$. That is, $p$ divides $(m+i)(m-i)$ in $\Bbb Z[i]$. Since this ring is an UFD, we can deduce that if $p$ were a prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$ then $p$ would divide $m+i$ or $m-i$, but this is clearly impossible. Then $p$ is not a prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$.

We use again the fact of $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a UFD to write:
$$p=zw$$
where $z=a+bi$ is a prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$. But $p=\bar z\bar w$. We deduce that if a prime divides $p$, its conjugate divides $p$, too. Therefore $p$ is a product of some primes and their conjugates, that is, the product of two conjugate complex numbers, or
$$p=u^2+v^2$$

Since $p$ is odd, $u$ or $v$ is even, say $2y$ and the other is odd, say $x$. Then $p=x^2+4y^2$.

**Remark**: in fact, a such prime $p$ can have only two prime divisors: $p=(u+iv)(u-iv)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also trying to find a proof for the same statement with 4 replaced by 7. The only problem would be the last step. Can you think of a way to dodge that?